# Magento 2: How to override Catalog Model class in custom extension?

Tags: magento2, custom, extend, watermark

I am trying to extend `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder` class in the custom extension and I have passed all the parameters of parent constructor but I'm getting this error,

```
  Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Management\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder, Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\
  ParamsBuilder::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\Model\Context give
  n, called in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Vendor\Management/Model/Product/Image/ParamsBuilder.php on line 33
```

In **`di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder" type="Vendor\Management\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder"/>
</config>
```

In **`Vendor\Management\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Management\Model\Product\Image;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder as MainModel;

class ParamsBuilder extends MainModel
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $viewConfig;
    
    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param ConfigInterface $viewConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ConfigInterface $viewConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->viewConfig = $viewConfig;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $scopeConfig,
            $viewConfig
        );
    }
    /**
     * Get watermark
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param int $scopeId
     * @return array
     */
    private function getWatermark(string $type, int $scopeId = null): array
    {
        $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(print_r("In getWatermark",true));

        $file = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            "design/watermark/{$type}_image",
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $scopeId
        );

        if ($file) {
            $size = explode(
                'x',
                (string) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    "design/watermark/{$type}_size",
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $scopeId
                )
            );
            $opacity = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                "design/watermark/{$type}_imageOpacity",
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $scopeId
            );
            $position = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                "design/watermark/{$type}_position",
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $scopeId
            );
            $width = !empty($size['0']) ? $size['0'] : null;
            $height = !empty($size['1']) ? $size['1'] : null;

            return [
                'watermark_file' => $file,
                'watermark_image_opacity' => $opacity,
                'watermark_position' => $position,
                'watermark_width' => $width,
                'watermark_height' => $height
            ];
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

The actual params builder class which i am extending is

**`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image;

/**
 * Builds parameters array used to build Image Asset
 */
class ParamsBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $defaultBackground = [255, 255, 255];

    /**
     * @var int|null
     */
    private $defaultAngle = null;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $defaultKeepAspectRatio = true;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $defaultKeepTransparency = true;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $defaultConstrainOnly = true;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $viewConfig;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param ConfigInterface $viewConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ConfigInterface $viewConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->viewConfig = $viewConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Build image params
     *
     * @param array $imageArguments
     * @param int $scopeId
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function build(array $imageArguments, int $scopeId = null): array
    {
        $miscParams = [
            'image_type' => $imageArguments['type'] ?? null,
            'image_height' => $imageArguments['height'] ?? null,
            'image_width' => $imageArguments['width'] ?? null,
        ];

        $overwritten = $this->overwriteDefaultValues($imageArguments);
        $watermark = isset($miscParams['image_type']) ? $this->getWatermark($miscParams['image_type'], $scopeId) : [];

        return array_merge($miscParams, $overwritten, $watermark);
    }

    /**
     * Overwrite default values
     *
     * @param array $imageArguments
     * @return array
     */
    private function overwriteDefaultValues(array $imageArguments): array
    {
        $frame = $imageArguments['frame'] ?? $this->hasDefaultFrame();
        $constrain = $imageArguments['constrain'] ?? $this->defaultConstrainOnly;
        $aspectRatio = $imageArguments['aspect_ratio'] ?? $this->defaultKeepAspectRatio;
        $transparency = $imageArguments['transparency'] ?? $this->defaultKeepTransparency;
        $background = $imageArguments['background'] ?? $this->defaultBackground;
        $angle = $imageArguments['angle'] ?? $this->defaultAngle;
        $quality = (int) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(Image::XML_PATH_JPEG_QUALITY);

        return [
            'background' => (array) $background,
            'angle' => $angle,
            'quality' => $quality,
            'keep_aspect_ratio' => (bool) $aspectRatio,
            'keep_frame' => (bool) $frame,
            'keep_transparency' => (bool) $transparency,
            'constrain_only' => (bool) $constrain,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get watermark
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param int $scopeId
     * @return array
     */
    private function getWatermark(string $type, int $scopeId = null): array
    {
        $file = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            "design/watermark/{$type}_image",
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $scopeId
        );

        if ($file) {
            $size = explode(
                'x',
                (string) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    "design/watermark/{$type}_size",
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $scopeId
                )
            );
            $opacity = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                "design/watermark/{$type}_imageOpacity",
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $scopeId
            );
            $position = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                "design/watermark/{$type}_position",
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $scopeId
            );
            $width = !empty($size['0']) ? $size['0'] : null;
            $height = !empty($size['1']) ? $size['1'] : null;

            return [
                'watermark_file' => $file,
                'watermark_image_opacity' => $opacity,
                'watermark_position' => $position,
                'watermark_width' => $width,
                'watermark_height' => $height
            ];
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get frame from product_image_white_borders
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function hasDefaultFrame(): bool
    {
        return (bool) $this->viewConfig->getViewConfig(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND])
            ->getVarValue('Magento_Catalog', 'product_image_white_borders');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove $cntext and $registry in your construct:

```
public function __construct(
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ConfigInterface $viewConfig
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $scopeConfig,
        $viewConfig
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried but then there is nothing logged in getwatermark() method.

Comment: getwatermark is the private method, how I can override it?

Comment: You cannot do it. The only way is to rewrite the whole class, not extend it.

Comment: Can you refer to some example links?

Comment: Copy the whole class in Vendor\Management\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder.php then add your customizations.

Comment: It then gives more issues like
`Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\MediaStorage\Service\ImageResize, Argument 5 passed to Magento\MediaStorage\Service\ImageResize::__cons
  truct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder, instance of Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder given,
   called in /var/www/html/opensooq/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121`

Comment: Do i still need to add code in di.xml? If i copy the whole code?

Comment: I did the same way you asked. but I can confirm the changes are not reflecting.